# How to copy marked lines in a Textpad...?

Tags: database, database-administration, microsoft-office

I had exported the table structure of my live Database.And open it with help of Textpad.It is very huge file and i want to copy a particular lines from the textpad.I mean,i want to copy marked lines only from the Textpad.Otherwise delete all other content except the Marked lines.

Answer (score 3):

Answer for the above Question is

goto edit -> Copy Other -> Bookmarked lines. You are done!